# Why does this error occur in my code?

Tags: c++

My compiler gives an error "Could not find a match for 'ostream::write(S1,int)'"
in this code .The part where the compiler gives an error is commented

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    struct S1
    {
        char*str;
        S1*ptr;
    };

    S1 arr[]={" Aanna ",arr+1," Neha ",arr+2," Simran ",arr};

    S1*p[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
        p[i]=arr[i].ptr;

    cout.write(p[0]->str,7).put('\n');
    cout.write((*p)->str,7).put('\n');
    cout.write(**p,7).put('\n');//why doesn't it work
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first header you include is not a standard header and should have the extension removed. The second is deprecated and should be replaced with the `<c…>` version.

Comment: 1) What error 2) What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I wrote that part thinking that *p gives the address stored at arr+1 and **p gives " Neha ". Why isn't this logic applicable?

Comment: we use the old tc3 version which is 8 yrs old its outdated but our school requires the use of it

Comment: @user3211362, Not 8, 23 (Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991). That's mighty old for a compiler.

Answer (score 6):

`**p` has type `S1`. There is no overloaded version of `ostream::write` which knows about `S1` , so you get an error.

I will go out on a limb and guess that you meant to put `p[0]->ptr->str`

Comment: no I wrote that part thinking that *p gives the address stored at arr+1 and **p gives " Neha ". Why isn't this logic applicable?

Comment: `*p` does not give "the address stored at arr+1", not at all. `p` as type "array of 3 pointers to S1". So `*p` (which means the same as `p[0]`) has type "pointer to S1".  When you apply `*` to "pointer to S1", you get `S1`.

Comment: The value of `p[0]` is `arr+1`, so `*p[0]` (same as `**p`) designates the same memory location as `arr[1]`.

Comment: `p[0]->str` is " Neha ", `p[0]->ptr` is `arr+2`